# How can I gather resources to afford the later base upgrades?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I had no trouble buying a full set of level 1 and 2 upgrades for my mother base. However, the cost of upgrades balloons by level 3 - it takes 16k in two resources. I've filled my base development unit with highly rated soldiers, but that doesn't seem to increase my material acquisition enough to afford the upgrades. I can:

- gather processed resources in the field, but at 50 to 100 a pop... that's not particularly efficient.
- fulton the shipping containers for 750-7500 **unprocessed** resources, but these seem to not be so useful as my mother base currently processes resources at roughly the same speed as it generates its own.

What can I do to generate resources efficiently? If I can barely afford level 3 upgrades, I shudder at the thought of level 4 prices...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that after Grade 3 or 4 you will need to rely on your online FOB to help you with the resource processing. (Since it will allow you to assign even more staff to Base Development) Otherwise, without the online features the best bet is to maximize the skill in the Base Development unit by assigning more high grade staff, and letting go the low skilled one.

It also takes time to process the resources, so you shouldn't push for all the upgrades, but instead aim for those you need, then the upgrades for your Security, and finally the extra ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

Resources can also be obtained from:

1. Combat Deployments, choose the jobs that pay the necessary resource
2. PF Point Exchange, if you successfully infiltrate an FOB, or defend your own, you gain PF points, which can be used to purchase resources

Comment: PF points are completely separate from FOBs. The PF system puts you in a league of 16 people and over the course of a week you will have virtual battles with the other 15 people (1 attack and 1 defence each person). Each win will give you one point (max is 30). Depending on your league position at the end of the week you will be promoted (or presumably demoted) and awarded PF points.  The stats for attack and defence are modelled on your bases combat and security team levels. You can see all the scheduled match times on one of the tabs in the PF menu.